# To resolve Subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a VBA code to consolidate some Excel workbooks and perform an operation on it but it keeps returning **subscript out of range error** after consolidating the workbooks... Please I need help!

```
Sub ConsolidateAll()

    Dim Path As Variant
    Dim Name As Variant
    Dim wkbConsol As Workbook
    Dim wbk2 As Workbook
    Dim wksConsol As Worksheet
    Dim wkbOpen As Workbook
    Dim wksOpen As Worksheet
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Cnt As Long

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wkbConsol = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wksConsol = wkbConsol.Worksheets(1)

    'Change the path accordingly
    FolderName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New folder"

    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> "\" Then FolderName = FolderName & "\"

    FileName = Dir(FolderName & "*.csv")

    Cnt = 1
    Do While FileName <> ""
        If FileName <> wkbConsol.Name Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Opening " & FileName & "..."
            Set wkbOpen = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & FileName)
            Set wksOpen = wkbOpen.Worksheets(1)
            Application.StatusBar = "Copying the data from " & FileName & "..."
            With wksOpen.UsedRange
                If Cnt = 1 Then
                    .Copy
                    wksConsol.Cells(1, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Else
                    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy
                    wksConsol.Cells(wksConsol.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                End If
            End With
            wkbOpen.Close savechanges:=False
            Application.StatusBar = FileName & " closed..."
        End If
        FileName = Dir
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
    Loop

    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Name = Dir(Path & "*Time Login-Logout*.csv")
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(Path & Name)

    wbk2.Activate
    Sheets("Time Login-Logout").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    wkbConsol.Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Columns("A:I").Select
    Selection.Copy

    wbk2.Activate
    Sheets("Time Login-Logout").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Application.StatusBar = False
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The consolidating works but the code after the wbk2 workbook is opened does not...

Comment: What line generates the error?

Comment: Subscript out of Range typically means you're referring to an object member of a collection which does not exist in the collection (check for typos when referring to worksheets or workbooks by *name*). Does `wbk2` *have* a worksheet named `"Time Login-Logout"? I suspect it doesn't.

Comment: It does have the worksheet "Time Login-Logout" however, suggestion from @Tim Williams did resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The sheet in `wkbk2` should have the same name as the CSV filename (without the extension) - but that will not be necessarily be "Time Login-Logout" since you're using wildcards in your call to `Dir()`.

However, since there's only one sheet in a workbook opened from a CSV then it's safe to just use `wkbk2.Sheets(1)` instead.

Try this:

```
    '...
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Name = Dir(Path & "*Time Login-Logout*.csv")
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(Path & Name)

    With wbk2.Sheets(1)
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Range("A:I").Value = wkbConsol.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:I").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to even create a **.csv** file with an *asterisk* in the file name ??